# Could someone please advise why the following CSS won't center a paragraph and relating div?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I'm having difficulty trying to figure out why my CSS won't style my HTML how I think it should. I'd really appreciate some help.

So basically, I have this HTML markup:

```
<div id="things">
    <p>A few things I couldn't live without:</p>
    <br><br>
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="http://www.google.ie" target="_blank"><img alt="Google icon" src="images/google.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" target="_blank"><img alt="Wikipedia icon" src="images/wikipedia.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Youtube icon" src="images/youtube.png"/></a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter icon" src="images/twitter.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook icon" src="images/facebook.png"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.whatsapp.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Whatsapp icon" src="images/whatsapp.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like for the paragraph and the `class="icons"` to be centered in their div.

I have the following CSS:

```
#things {
    width:31%;
    float:left;
}   

#things p{
    float:left;
    margin:3.5% auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.icons{
    float:left;
    margin:4% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Could anyone please advise? Thanks

Comment: If you want them to be centered first remove `float:left;`

Comment: I think Zword is right - looks like it should work without the floats.

Comment: @smclark89 yeah I've tried that but still can't get it working, guess I'll have to keep searching!

Answer (score 1):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyxYL/)

**Updated CSS**

```
#things {
    width:31%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}   

#things p{
    margin:3.5% auto 0 auto;
}

.icons{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the `float: left;` on anything you want centered to begin with.

**EDIT**

Looks like i was beaten to it in the comments!